# Parsing elements in Python from SQL Database

Tags: python, sql

in Python v3.6: I have an entry coming in from database as a "single" string as follows:

`'[snp500, vix]'`

However I wish to read it as as a "list" of strings

**`['snp500', 'vix']`**

Can you please help how can I achieve this?

Comment: Which database and connector package are you using?  And what is the type of the column in the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
x = '[snp500, vix]'
```

You want to split around the `[` brackets:

```
x = '[snp500, vix]'[1:-1].split(", ")
# ['np500', 'vi']
```

A safer method would be to use `re`:

```
import re
re.split(",\s*", '[snp500, vix]'[1:-1])
```

This solution allows for 0 or more spaces after the comma.